# How to use 'rows.add(...)' in jQuery DataTable?

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, datatables

> I solved it by looping through data.courseApplications and adding a new row for each element and adding each column, e.g. **row.add([{data.courseApplications[i].col1, ...,data.courseApplications[i].colN}])**. But this does not feel sufficient

I am new to jQuery DataTables, and I am trying to reinitialize a datatable on
a click event on a hyperlink. Initializing the datatable works fine (with knockout binding, creating the table etc), but when I click on another event, the datatable will not reinitialize.

I have attacked this problem in two differentways, one where I clear the existing datatable and redraw it. The second way is to destroy the datatable and recreate it.

I get the following error when I try to 'reinitialize' the datatable by clearing it first, then adding the array "data.courseApplications" (which  contains the correct data) as rows.

> DataTables warning: table id=coursemoment-info-table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

This error occurs on this line in the "viewOnClickEvent"-method. **Notice that
the datatable "shows" the correct amount of entries/rows, but without content**.

```
    $("#coursemoment-info-table").DataTable().rows.add(data.courseApplications);
```

The following code shows my first attempt.

Html:

```
<div class="row mb-0" data-bind="visible:!loadingCourseMoment()">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card-block pt-0">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table id="coursemoment-info-table"  class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr >
                                      // headers
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                    <!-- ko foreach: selectedCourseMoment().courseApplications -->
                                    <tr>

                                       // bindings

                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- /ko-->
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

Init datatable:

`private initCourseMomentInformationDataTable(): void {
        $("#coursemoment-info-table").DataTable({
            pageLength: 5,
            order: [1, 'desc'],
            language: {
                url: "/Assets/js/jquery-datatable-swedish.json"
            }
        });
    }`

Redraw on clickevent:

```
public viewCourseApplicationsClick = (selectedCourseMoment: ICourseMoment): void => {
    this.loadingCourseMoment(true);
    this.courseService.getCourseMomentByCourseNumber(selectedCourseMoment.courseNr)
        .then((data: any) => {
            this.selectedCourseMoment(data);
            if (this.tableInitiliazed) {
                $("#coursemoment-info-table").DataTable().clear().draw();
                $("#coursemoment-info-table").DataTable().rows.add(data.courseApplications); 
                $("#coursemoment-info-table").DataTable().columns().draw(); 
            } else {
                this.initCourseMomentInformationDataTable();
                this.tableInitiliazed = true;
            }

            this.loadingCourseMoment(false);

        }).catch((reason:any) => {
           console.log(reason);
        });
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think the issue is when you are trying to add rows to datatable.  Please check this line '$("#coursemoment-info-table").DataTable().rows.add(data.courseApplications)'. in this may be data.courseApplications is null

Comment: Hi, that did not help. I came up with a solution and added it to the post, but it feels insufficient.

Comment: You cannot have both Knockout and DataTable manage the DOM. You should be using a [binding handler for DataTables](https://github.com/JohnBergman/knockout.datatables) and be manipulating data, not manipulating the DOM.

Comment: I've never used Datatables, but what's wrong with using Knockout? [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Nhawdge/kr45k9on/) Is a fiddle I made for another question